How to Improve Kernel Density Estimation Plot Map Grid Cells for Vessel Traffic on the West Coast of Mexico in R?
I'm working on visualizing vessel traffic density for the west coast of Mexico, including Baja California and Bahia de Banderas waters, using R. I have a large dataset of vessel locations stored in a list, from which I've extracted the latitude and longitude values. After filtering the data to focus on the region of interest and removing outliers, I performed kernel density estimation (KDE) to create a smooth density surface. However, the resulting density plot does not look as expected; it shows a sparse distribution of density values despite the large number of data points.
I have ensured the data falls within the correct geographic bounds and increased the grid resolution for finer detail. I'm including the code I've used and an image of the current density plot for reference. Any suggestions on how to improve the density plot or identify potential issues in my approach would be greatly appreciated.
###Vessel Density

# Install packages if not already installed
install.packages(c("sp", "raster", "ggplot2", "MASS", "viridis"))

# Load packages
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(viridis)

# Inspect the structure of data.cleaned to confirm it contains longitude and latitude
str(data.cleaned)

# Inspect the structure of SSM_2023_2024 (if needed for later use)
str(SSM_2023_2024)

# Print the first few entries of data.cleaned to verify content
print("First few entries of data.cleaned:")
print(head(data.cleaned))

# Check the names of the elements in data.cleaned
print(names(data.cleaned))

# Print the first few entries of data.cleaned to verify content
print("First few entries of data.cleaned:")
print(head(data.cleaned, n = 1))  # Print the first element to check its structure

# Extract latitude and longitude from the list
latitude <- unlist(lapply(data.cleaned, function(x) x$latitude))
longitude <- unlist(lapply(data.cleaned, function(x) x$longitude))

# Print the first few entries of latitude and longitude to verify
print("First few entries of latitude:")
print(head(latitude))

print("First few entries of longitude:")
print(head(longitude))

# Convert the extracted data to numeric
longitude <- as.numeric(longitude)
latitude <- as.numeric(latitude)

# Check if the coordinates are correctly converted to numeric
if (length(longitude) == 0 | length(latitude) == 0) {
  stop("Longitude or latitude columns are empty after conversion. Please check the data.")
}


# Check for any missing values and remove them if necessary
longitude <- na.omit(longitude)
latitude <- na.omit(latitude)

# Ensure they have the same length after omitting NAs
if (length(longitude) != length(latitude)) {
  stop("Longitude and Latitude vectors have different lengths after omitting NAs.")
}

# Create a data frame from the extracted latitude and longitude
vessel_data <- data.frame(longitude, latitude)

# Sample a subset of the data if the full dataset is too large to handle
# Sample, e.g., 1% of the data
set.seed(123)  # Setting seed for reproducibility
sample_indices <- sample(1:nrow(vessel_data), size = 0.01 * nrow(vessel_data))
vessel_data_sampled <- vessel_data[sample_indices, ]

# Check the structure and summary of the sampled data
print("Summary of the sampled data:")
print(summary(vessel_data_sampled))

# Create a spatial object for the sampled vessel data
coordinates(vessel_data_sampled) <- ~longitude + latitude

# Print the summary of the spatial object
print("Summary of the spatial object vessel_data_sampled:")
print(summary(vessel_data_sampled))

# Define the extent of the grid
x_range <- range(vessel_data_sampled$longitude, na.rm = TRUE)
y_range <- range(vessel_data_sampled$latitude, na.rm = TRUE)
n_x <- 100  # number of cells in x-direction
n_y <- 100  # number of cells in y-direction

grid <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(x_range[1], x_range[2], length.out = n_x),
  y = seq(y_range[1], y_range[2], length.out = n_y)
)
coordinates(grid) <- ~x + y
gridded(grid) <- TRUE

# Print the grid summary to check if it's correct
print("Summary of the grid:")
print(summary(grid))

# Extract coordinates from the vessel data
vessel_coords <- coordinates(vessel_data_sampled)

# Perform kernel density estimation
kde <- kde2d(vessel_coords[, 1], vessel_coords[, 2], n = c(n_x, n_y), lims = c(x_range, y_range))

# Convert KDE results to a raster
kde_raster <- raster(kde)

# Print the summary of the KDE raster to check if it's correct
print("Summary of the KDE raster:")
print(summary(kde_raster))

# Convert raster to a dataframe for plotting with ggplot2
kde_df <- as.data.frame(as(kde_raster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))

# Print the first few entries of the dataframe to verify
print("First few entries of the KDE dataframe:")
print(head(kde_df))

# Plot using ggplot2
ggplot(kde_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  labs(
    title = "Vessel Traffic Density",
    x = "Longitude",
    y = "Latitude",
    fill = "Density"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

####Verify
# Summary of longitude and latitude values
summary(vessel_data$longitude)
summary(vessel_data$latitude)

# Plot a scatter plot of the data to inspect the distribution
ggplot(vessel_data_sampled, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Scatter Plot of Vessel Data", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")

# Define a higher resolution grid
n_x <- 200  # Increased number of cells in x-direction
n_y <- 200  # Increased number of cells in y-direction

# Perform kernel density estimation on the sampled data
kde <- kde2d(vessel_coords[, 1], vessel_coords[, 2], n = c(n_x, n_y), lims = c(x_range, y_range))

# Convert KDE results to a raster
kde_raster <- raster(kde)

# Convert raster to a dataframe for plotting with ggplot2
kde_df <- as.data.frame(as(kde_raster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))

# Plot using ggplot2  ############ERROR 
ggplot(kde_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  labs(
    title = "Vessel Traffic Density",
    x = "Longitude",
    y = "Latitude",
    fill = "Density"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()


##########################################IN CHUNKS 
# Function to process chunks of data
process_chunk <- function(chunk) {
  # Extract latitude and longitude from the chunk
  latitude <- as.numeric(na.omit(chunk$latitude))
  longitude <- as.numeric(na.omit(chunk$longitude))
  
  # Return a data frame
  data.frame(longitude, latitude)
}

# Initialize an empty list to store processed chunks
processed_chunks <- list()

# Process each chunk in the data.cleaned list
for (i in seq_along(data.cleaned)) {
  chunk <- data.cleaned[[i]]
  processed_chunk <- process_chunk(chunk)
  processed_chunks[[i]] <- processed_chunk
}

# Combine all processed chunks into one data frame
vessel_data_combined <- do.call(rbind, processed_chunks)

# Print the structure and summary of the combined data
print("Summary of the combined data:")
print(summary(vessel_data_combined))

# Sample a subset of the data if the full dataset is too large to handle
set.seed(123)  # Setting seed for reproducibility
sample_indices <- sample(1:nrow(vessel_data_combined), size = 0.01 * nrow(vessel_data_combined))
vessel_data_sampled <- vessel_data_combined[sample_indices, ]

# Check the structure and summary of the sampled data
print("Summary of the sampled data:")
print(summary(vessel_data_sampled))

# Ensure vessel_data_sampled is a data frame
vessel_data_sampled <- as.data.frame(vessel_data_sampled)

# Create a spatial object for the sampled vessel data
coordinates(vessel_data_sampled) <- ~longitude + latitude

# Print the summary of the spatial object
print("Summary of the spatial object vessel_data_sampled:")
print(summary(vessel_data_sampled))

# Define the grid with higher resolution
x_range <- range(vessel_data_sampled$longitude, na.rm = TRUE)
y_range <- range(vessel_data_sampled$latitude, na.rm = TRUE)
n_x <- 200  # Increased number of cells in x-direction
n_y <- 200  # Increased number of cells in y-direction

grid <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(x_range[1], x_range[2], length.out = n_x),
  y = seq(y_range[1], y_range[2], length.out = n_y)
)
coordinates(grid) <- ~x + y
gridded(grid) <- TRUE

# Print the grid summary to check if it's correct
print("Summary of the grid:")
print(summary(grid))

# Extract coordinates from the vessel data
vessel_coords <- coordinates(vessel_data_sampled)

# Perform kernel density estimation
kde <- kde2d(vessel_coords[, 1], vessel_coords[, 2], n = c(n_x, n_y), lims = c(x_range, y_range))

# Convert KDE results to a raster
kde_raster <- raster(kde)

# Print the summary of the KDE raster to check if it's correct
print("Summary of the KDE raster:")
print(summary(kde_raster))

# Convert raster to a dataframe for plotting with ggplot2
kde_df <- as.data.frame(as(kde_raster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))

# Print the first few entries of the dataframe to verify
print("First few entries of the KDE dataframe:")
print(head(kde_df))

# Plot using ggplot2
ggplot(kde_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  labs(
    title = "Vessel Traffic Density",
    x = "Longitude",
    y = "Latitude",
    fill = "Density"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()



As with your previous question, it's harder to help without a copy of your data. Either add the results of runningdput() on your datasets, or if they are too large to include in your question, add download links. Also, there is a lot of unnecessary code in your question which makes it harder to find the problem. Please consider trimming your code to a minimal example e.g. we don't need things like str(), print() etc. Thanks, and good luck!
